# Cannot access locked file in Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm having difficulty with a simple Windows script. This examines the current directory, stores the names of the (assumed to be 2) text files in an array, and then runs fc to compare them, piping the output to a text file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
IF EXIST comparison.txt del /F comparison.txt
set filename=
set /a N=0
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
    set /a N+=1
    set v[!N!]=%%a
)
fc %v[1]% %v[2]% > comparison.txt
```

When I run this I get the error message "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

I've tried variants where I write the completed fc command line to another BAT file and then call that but with the same result (note that the actual fc code appears to be correct in this—it has the correct file names and output redirection destination). After trying to run the BAT once, I then even get the same error if I pull up an interactive command line and type the fc command manually. This doesn't happen if I type the command without first running the BAT.

This is on Win 7 x64, Version 6.1.7601.

Comment: @RGuggisberg "Comparison.txt is included in the files you are iterating through" - no it's not. Adding `echo %%a` will prove it.

Comment: I cannot repro this. Your batch file works perfectly when testing here. Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit

Comment: @DavidPostill, You are right. I should have looked a bit closer :)

Comment: Just tried modified ver where I simply create a BAT with fc in it as output. When I try to run this (i.e. outside the prog above), still get the same error, or find that the contents of the 2nd BAT now refer to the output (comparison.txt) in the input to fc—before it's even been created!